# Solving a system of complex equations.

Tags: linear-algebra

I've got the following system of equations to solve with $u,v\in \mathbb{C}$, but I dont really know how to start:

$$u^2-v\overline{v}+1=0,\\
uv+\overline{u}v=0,\\ -u\overline{v}-\overline{u}\overline{v}=0,\\ -\overline{v}v+\overline{u}^2+1 =0$$

I tried to factor some things but it only confuses me, because the variables are complex.

Can somebody help me any further,

Thanks

Comment: $uv + \bar{u}v = 0$ can be rewritten as $(u+\bar{u})v = 0$, and thus tells you that either $v=0$ or $u$ is purely imaginary (because only then $u + \bar{u} = 0$). Something similar should work for $-u\bar{v}-\bar{u}\bar{v} = 0$.

Comment: for the first one wouldn't $u$ be purely real?  If $u=a+bi, $then you get $a+bi+a-bi=2a$.

Comment: @ChristopherErnst Exactly, and for that to be zero, $a$ needs to be zero, which makes $u$ purely imaginary, i.e. of the form $ib$ for some $b \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: nevermind....I made a mistake... then $a=0$.  I should have finished the argument...  oops!!   :)

Comment: BTW, the third equation is equivalent to the second (conjugate the second equation and multiply by $-1$), and the fourth equation is equivalent to the first (conjugate the first equation). So you can restrict your attention to the first two equations....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it like this:

$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
u^2-v\overline{v}+1 = 0  \wedge (u+\overline{u})v= 0 \Leftrightarrow\\
(v=0  \wedge u^2+1=0) \vee (u+\overline{u} = 0 \wedge u^2-v\overline{v}+1=0) \Leftrightarrow\\
(v=0 \wedge (u=i \vee u=-i)) \vee (\overline{u}=-u \wedge |u|^2+|v|^2=1) \Leftrightarrow \\
\overline{u} = (-u) \wedge (|u|^2+|v|^2=1) \Leftrightarrow\\
u=iu_2 \wedge (v=v_1+iv_2) \wedge (u_2^2+v_1^2+v_2^2=1) \wedge (u_2,v_1,v_2\in\mathbb{R}).
\end{eqnarray*}
$$

Thanks for the replies!